# A function that is continuous but non differentiable at a countable no of points.

Tags: real-analysis

My Question is :
Construct a function which is continuous on $[0,1]$ but not differentiable at exactly countably infinite points.

I cannot construct this example.
please help.

Thank you ...!!

Comment: $y = |\cos(x)|$?

Comment: But sir $y=|cos x|$ is differentiable on [0,1]...@ Kaynex

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. My mistake.

Comment: we can modify it a bit. Take $|x\cos(1/x)|$ and make $f(0)=0$.

Comment: yes....!! Thanks ...@ J F Hidalgo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider the point $(0,1)$ and $(1/n,(-1)^n)$ for positive integers $n$, the piecewise linear function joining those consecutive points does the trick. It is only not differentiable at $x=\frac{1}{n}$ with $n>1$.

Comment: Thank you sir....I got it....

Comment: no problem, happy to help.